# GCP SSL Proxy LoadBalancer via Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, load-balancing

We are creating infrastructure on GCP for our application which uses SSL Porxy Load Balancer on GCP. We use Terraform for our deployments and are struggling to create SSL Proxy Load Balancer via terraform.

If anyone could point to a sample code or point me to a direction where I can find some resources to create the load balancer

Comment: There are a number of Terraform experts on Stackoverflow. However, if you do not show effort in specifying your problem, showing your work and the problems you are experiencing, .... Invest time in your question and problem solving. Here is a link to help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_target_ssl_proxy):

```
resource "google_compute_target_ssl_proxy" "default" {
  name             = "test-proxy"
  backend_service  = google_compute_backend_service.default.id
  ssl_certificates = [google_compute_ssl_certificate.default.id]
}

resource "google_compute_ssl_certificate" "default" {
  name        = "default-cert"
  private_key = file("path/to/private.key")
  certificate = file("path/to/certificate.crt")
}

resource "google_compute_backend_service" "default" {
  name          = "backend-service"
  protocol      = "SSL"
  health_checks = [google_compute_health_check.default.id]
}

resource "google_compute_health_check" "default" {
  name               = "health-check"
  check_interval_sec = 1
  timeout_sec        = 1
  tcp_health_check {
    port = "443"
  }
}
```

Take onto consideration that the `Health Check` is pointed to port `443/tcp`, if you want a different port please change that on here.